# USB ports stopped working (code 19)

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, windows-registry

Last week all usb ports of my laptop Lenovo B575 with Windows 7 stopped working but on Linux everything is all right. I've figured out in Device Manager that the problem lies somewhere in the registry (code 19).

So far I've tried reinstalling usb drivers but nothing happened. I've also tried uninstalling all usb devices listed in Device Manager and let Windows autoinstall them after reboot but it only showed a message that Windows actually failed to install them.

I don't want to go to extreme measures and reinstall Windows, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using [Last Known Good Configuration](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-last-known-good-configuration#1TC=windows-7)? Have you got any [restore points](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/system-restore)?

Comment: Does this only happen when you're on battery, or also when connected? What devices work/don't work? (trying to see if it's a power fluctuation issue)

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy It happens no matter if I'm connected or not. In Device Manager it is written that all 3 standard openHCD usb host controllers and 2 Standard Enhanced PCI to USB Host Controllers don't work. I've tried to plug various devices like mouses, gamepads, pendrives but none of them worked.

Comment: @and31415 Unfortunately, I tried using last known good configuration but it didn't help.

Comment: @user2648421 What about restore points? Did you try using the official [USB diagnostic tool](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9802032) already? What's the exact error message when you uninstall all USB devices and let Windows install them again? Also, are all non-USB devices working properly?

Comment: I've tried diagnostic tool but with no success. All non usb devices work like a charm. When I uninstall all USB devices and then autoinstall them Windows shows something like "Searching for preconfigured drivers" and after long time for every USB port it is written just "Failure".